# Problem during installing tailwind postcss?

Tags: tailwind-css

I run command
**npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer**

and got the following errors.

npm ERR! code ERR_SSL_CIPHER_OPERATION_FAILED
npm ERR! 381B0000:error:1C800066:Provider routines:ossl_gcm_stream_update:cipher operation failed:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\providers\implementations\ciphers\ciphercommon_gcm.c:320:
npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Solution\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-01-29T11_18_03_244Z-debug-0.log

I tried to solve this problem but couldn't.
I need to install tailwind using postcss.

Comment: which node version you are using ?